# How does Enlightenment feel like

Tags: meditation, enlightenment, meditation-insight, meditation-effects

Finally everyone who meditate comes to a single point **"Enlightenment"**. So anybody have any idea about how the enlightenment feels like. How it helps a man. How their mind works and reacts to the situations.

How important is enlightenment to a man. Do we need to meditate more hours to gain enlightenment or Meditate effectively to get enlightened.

Answer (score 1):

Here is you can get a clue how it like the enlightenment. Reading this sutta superficially will not guarantee  the total realization of Nirvana. But surely get clue.

The heart sutta;

Body is nothing more than emptiness, 
emptiness is nothing more than body. 
The body is exactly empty, 
and emptiness is exactly body.
The other four aspects of human existence -- 
feeling, thought, will, and consciousness -- 
are likewise nothing more than emptiness, 
and emptiness nothing more than they.

All things are empty: 
Nothing is born, nothing dies, 
nothing is pure, nothing is stained, 
nothing increases and nothing decreases.

(So anybody have any idea about how the enlightment feels like)The question is how you imagine the feeling of this kind. you have to think,meditate and find the wisdom to realization. Its like explain color to born blind. Also you get full enlightment after parinibbana or death of person who attained Nirvana through realization.

***So, in emptiness, there is no body, 
no feeling, no thought, 
no will, no consciousness. 
There are no eyes, no ears, 
no nose, no tongue, 
no body, no mind. 
There is no seeing, no hearing, 
no smelling, no tasting, 
no touching, no imagining. 
There is nothing seen, nor heard, 
nor smelled, nor tasted, 
nor touched, nor imagined.***

Note: After reading above phrase you have to think deeply what is this "condition or state" , can anybody "feel" the above condition, and most important thing is we can assure there is no suffering or pleasure ultimately to feel and so on.......

There is no ignorance, 
and no end to ignorance. 
There is no old age and death, 
and no end to old age and death. 
There is no suffering, no cause of suffering, 
no end to suffering, no path to follow. 
There is no attainment of wisdom, 
and no wisdom to attain.

The Bodhisattvas rely on the Perfection of Wisdom, 
and so with no delusions, 
they feel no fear, 
and ***have Nirvana here and now.***

All the Buddhas, 
past, present, and future, 
rely on the Perfection of Wisdom, 
and live in full enlightenment.

The Perfection of Wisdom is the greatest mantra. 
It is the clearest mantra, 
the highest mantra, 
the mantra that removes all suffering.

This is truth that cannot be doubted. 
Say it so:

Gaté, 
gaté, 
paragaté, 
parasamgaté. 
Bodhi! 
Svaha!
Which means...
Gone, 
gone, 
gone over, 
gone fully over. 
Awakened! 
So be it!
* Emptiness is the usual translation for the Buddhist term Sunyata (or Shunyata).  It refers to the fact that no thing -- including human existence -- has ultimate substantiality, which in turn means that no thing is permanent and no thing is totally independent of everything else.  In other words, everything in this world is interconnected and in constant flux.  A deep appreciation of this idea of emptiness thus saves us from the suffering caused by our egos, our attachments, and our resistance to change and loss.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you sit down and watch a whole movie. Being so engrossed in the movie, you cry when it comes to the sad parts, you laugh when it comes to the funny parts. When the main protaganist gets pursued by a murderer, you squirm in fear as though it is you who is being pursued. When the character gets stabbed to death by the murderer, you grimace in pain as though it is you who got stabbed.

After the character dies, you suddenly realize that you're not actually a character in the movie, and even if you continue to watch the movie, you no longer experience sufferings associated with the characters in the movie, and you don't have to try to accomplish anything in the movie.

The Buddha taught in the [Sona Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.055.than.html):

> When one's awareness is dedicated
>   to renunciation, seclusion,
>   non-afflictiveness, the ending of clinging,
>   the ending of craving, & non-deludedness,
>   seeing the arising of the sense media,
>   the mind is rightly released.
>
> For that monk, rightly released,
>   his heart at peace,
>   there's nothing to be done,
>   nothing to add to what's done.
>
> As a single mass of rock isn't moved by the wind,
>   even so all forms, flavors, sounds,
>   aromas, contacts, ideas
>   desirable & not,
>   have no effect on one who is Such.
>   The mind — still, totally released —
>   focuses on their passing away.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling is caused. Feeling belongs to the five aggregates. So technically there is no feeling in Enlightenment(Nibbana). However since the defilements are cut off, it is said that after one emerges from enlightenment, it may feel like a heavy burden has been taken off of one's shoulders or it may feel like how a cancer patient in extreme painful condition would feel, if he was suddenly cured. Here's a related [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/232/111).