# How to get to know the state of mind

Tags: theravada, stages-of-the-path

How to get to know mind has reached sakadagami state or still in sotapanna?During  meditation experience no thoughts and Feel like clear emptiness. Reached clear darkness  with peace of mind and there is a light with dark in sometime. And sexual craving disappears when meditation feel free after that. At which state of mind dependent origin will break?whether it is  just a jhana state .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"clear darkness with peace of mind" is an experience of Samadhi. It's neither Sothapanna nor Sakadagami. When you attain Sothapanna, it makes a permanent change in you. The self view, attachment to rites and rituals and doubt are removed permanently. It's not any kind of peaceful feeling that you get while meditating. Same goes for Sakadagami. When you attain it your craving towards sensual pleasure and aversion are permanently weakened regardless of if you are meditating or not.

Comment: Which samadhi,is it kanika samadhi

Comment: What is the state of mind in sotapanna?Isn't it peace reduce attachment to thoughts

Comment: kanika samadhi is moment to moment concentration.  Read [this answer on how Satapanna occurs](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/232/111).

Answer (score 2):

At sotapanna state, 3 of the 10 fetters will be disappeared from mind -- they are:

1. sakkayaditti (feeling of myself and mine)
2. wichikichcha (doubt on 8 things, includes buddha, dhamma, sanga, ...)
3. seelabbathaparamasa (follow wrong *silas*)

After sotapanna state, when your mind advance to sakadagami state, another 2 fetters will be reduced, but not completely removed from mind -- they are:

4. kamaraga (lust for 5 sensations we get from our eyes, ears, tongue, skin and nose)
5. wyapada( conflict with things we dislike..this is mainly the anger in our mind)

When you see these are reduced from your mind, after sotapanna state, it's sakadagami state.

That feeling of mind when it advanced to sakadagami state can't express to other person, you have to experience that feeling from yourself.

Sexual  cravings will completely remove from one's mind when he is advanced to the arahat state -- the last state of nirvana path. When you are in sakadagami or anagami state also, you have sexual  cravings in your mind, but they are reduced gradually than before.

When you meditate you can experience lights appear in front of you, that's called *Āloka-saññā* (or light signals) -- then if you need you can focus your mind on that light and meditate along, that's called *kasina bhawana*. But that may be not your target sometime, however from that you can get your mind to a jhana state... when you focus on light and meditate along that light will be larger in huge size... that is the first jhana.

(i haven't learnt buddhism much in English, just in pali an Sinhalese..so i don't know some English translations you use for pali words..sorry for that.. )

Comment: "[Fetters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetter_(Buddhism))" in English. People on this site use some Pali words, like the ones you used, perhaps using different spellings like *[Sila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_ethics)* and [Bhavana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhavana).

Comment: If sotapanna has not achieved and reduced kamaraga and wiyapada is it a just jhana state or sotapanna or sakadagami?

Comment: Before archiving sakadagami have to achieve sowan state..When it's jhana state there's a certain reduce of kamaraga and wiyapada, but just reducing kamaraga and wiyapada we can't certainly say jhana, It may varies according to meditation when doing anapasati we can see a huge bright light in first jhana state,like that...

Comment: @madhawavish in wiyapada have seen the thoughts process has come and action has stopped by another thought.  And when  the action has stopped there is a light darkness with peace of mind. Is it a jhana state?